# How to add a whitespace between all characters in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, whitespace

In Python 2.7 I would like to know how to add a whitespace between every single character in a .txt file (very big file). I know how to do it with Emacs but is very slow.

Input example:

```
122212121212121
212121212121212
121212121212121
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open(infile) as open_file:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as write_file:
        for line in open_file:
            write_file.write(" ".join(line))
```